# Exit a Makefile target called by parent without throwing an error

Tags: bash

Let's say that I have 2 targets:

```
test:
    # ...
    @$(MAKE) dosomething
    @echo test
    # ...

dosomething:
    # ...
    @if [ -z "$(SOMETHING)" ]; then exit 0; fi
    @echo dosomething
    # ...
```

I would like `echo test` to execute even if `$(SOMETHING)` is empty and `echo dosomething` only if `$(SOMETHING)` is not empty (which doesn't work with the example, it's still executed).

`exit 0` of course doesn't work here since `make` ignores non-negative exit in subshells used to execute instructions.

Is there any other way to skip the rest of the target without breaking further execution of `test` target? I could make the rest a single long instruction of else but wondering if there's a different command I'm maybe missing.

Comment: Please let me know whether the example is what you are looking for. Could you indicate how the expected output should look like?

Comment: Not quite, I edited my question to be more specific

Answer (score 1):

**Makefile**

```
all: test dosomething

test:
    @echo "hello"

dosomething:
    @if [ "a" = "a" ]; then\
        echo "world";\
        exit 0;\
    fi
```

Running: `make` will return:

```
hello
world
```